# Integer solutions of $kx^2=y^3-1$, where $k$ is given positive integer.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametrization

Can we generate some parametric family of integer solutions of $kx^2=y^3-1$, where $k$ is given positive integer.

I don't even know if there are finite or infinite number of solutions. For $k=7$, one of the solutions is $x=1,y=2$. I think will be only finite number of solutions to $7x^2=y^3-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each positive integer $k$,  $k x^2 - y^3 + 1$ defines an elliptic curve.  By [Siegel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Integral_points), it has only finitely many integer solutions.